# Copy entire list using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, csom

I need to export an entire list as a .csv file.
I actually have this code which works great but I need to write each
column I want to export:

```
$listTitle = "Example"
$list = $ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle($listTitle);
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery;
$query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>"
$listItems = $list.GetItems($query);
$ctx.Load($listItems);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
$tableau =@();
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $listItem['Title'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Description -value $listItem['Description'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Age -value $listItem['Age'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Sexe -value $listItem['Sexe'];
    $tableau += $result;
}
$CsvName2 = "Export_"+$ListTitle.replace(' ','_')+".csv"
$tableau | export-csv $CsvName2 -notype;
```

The part I want to improve is the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $listItem['Title'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Description -value $listItem['Description'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Age -value $listItem['Age'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Sexe -value $listItem['Sexe'];
    $tableau += $result;
}
```

I want the script collects all columns but I don't know how to do it...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need another `foreach` cycle:

Replace this:

```
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $listItem['Title'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Description -value $listItem['Description'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Age -value $listItem['Age'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Sexe -value $listItem['Sexe'];
    $tableau += $result;
}
```

with something similar:

```
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    foreach ($field in $listItem.Fields) 
    {
        if ($field.Hidden -eq $false)
        {
            $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name $field.Title -value $listItem[$field.InternalName]; 
        }
    }
    $tableau += $result;
}
```

Don't have access to PS now, but this should work (maybe with minor tweaks).

Comment: Thanks for you ultra-rapid answer !

The first test I made using your code resulted in a blank .csv file, I try to find the problem and tell you here.

Comment: Hi, can't fix the error... I'm quite a nooby in CSOM/Powershell